# Command rsync in crontab not syncing

Tags: linux, cron, rsync

I need to use rsync in crontab task, but it's not doing the task. I placed my code as follows:
* * * * * rsync -ar --delete --suffix=`date +.%F_%H-%M-%S` /home/user1/Desktop /backup

Answer (score 0):

If your crontab task is read from the global crontab file under `/etc`, you need to specify the user by which the task is executed.

The other thing I see is that the suffix needs to be set by a subexpression.
So it would look something like:

```sh
rsync -ar --delete --suffix=$(date +.%F_%H-%M-%S) /home/user1/Desktop /backup
```